# How to fix textarea at the bottom in Chat UI?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want the pane above textarea to be scrollable. I'm using flexbox for this.
How can I stop the scrolling in the outer container.
I could use `position:sticky` or `postion:fixed` with margin-bottom but the textarea itself can increase in size.
here is what I've tried so far.
https://codepen.io/pavanmehta/pen/dyGxYqZ?editors=1100.

I preferably don't wanna use javascript at all for this, If it can be done with flexbox/grid

Comment: Are you able to set a height to the inner container? `.scrolling-list`. Also, if you're able to provide code here, it'll help for future users in the case where the link no longer exists.

Comment: Adding to the above, if you can set a `max-height` on your outer container `.container`, you'll find your problem is solved.

Comment: I can't set height of the inner container.. I want it to be Height of outer container - text area height

Comment: I tried the Height property on the outer container and it seems to work.

Comment: Is that the right way?

Comment: Looks like you've solved it.